# Query for fetching last n rows excluding the last row 

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table with 400 rows. I want to select last 6 rows excluding the last row.

With the following code I am getting the last 6 rows but I don't want the last(400th) row to be there

```
SELECT * 
FROM ImagesInfo 
WHERE Image_Id IN 
     (    SELECT TOP 6 Image_Id 
          FROM ImagesInfo 
          ORDER BY Image_Id DESC )
```

Comment: Thanks everyone for giving answer. Almost all the answers are correct.

Answer (score 2):

Use the `ROW_NUMBER()` syntax

```
SELECT * 
from
(
   SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() over (ORDER By Image_ID) rn
   FROM yourtable 
) v
WHERE rn between x and y
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT top 6 *
FROM 
     (    SELECT TOP 7 *
          FROM ImagesInfo 
          ORDER BY Image_Id DESC 
     ) t
ORDER BY Image_Id
```

Comment: Ohh.. my bad.. i didnt notice your last order by clause.. +1 for your answer

Answer (score 1):

Look at **OFFSET**

`SELECT First Name + ' ' + Last Name FROM Employees ORDER BY First Name OFFSET 10 ROWS FETCH NEXT 5 ROWS ONLY;`

[Microsoft SQL Server Website]

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg699618.aspx

Answer (score 0):

What about:

```
SELECT * FROM ImagesInfo
WHERE Image_Id IN (SELECT TOP 6 Image_Id FROM ImagesInfo ORDER BY Image_Id DESC) AND
      Image_Id <> (SELECT TOP 1 Image_Id FROM ImagesInfo ORDER BY Image_Id DESC)
```

OR

```
SELECT * FROM ImagesInfo
WHERE Image_Id IN (SELECT TOP 6 Image_Id FROM ImagesInfo ORDER BY Image_Id DESC) AND
      Image_Id <> (SELECT MAX(Image_Id) FROM ImagesInfo)
```

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding correctly (I'm not certain) then you shoud be able to do:

```
SELECT * 
FROM ImagesInfo 
WHERE Image_Id IN 
     (    SELECT TOP 7 Image_Id 
          FROM ImagesInfo 
          ORDER BY Image_Id DESC )
     and Image_Id not IN
     (    SELECT TOP 1 Image_ID
          FROM ImagesInfo
          ORDER BY Image_Id DESC )
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

You Just have to eliminate the max record from the result set

```
 SELECT * 
FROM ImagesInfo 
WHERE Image_Id IN 
     (    SELECT TOP 6 Image_Id 
          FROM ImagesInfo 
          where Image_Id<> (select MAX(Image_Id) from ImagesInfo )
          ORDER BY Image_Id DESC )
```

**OR**

If you are using **sql server 2005 or above**:
you can use, [ROW_NUMBER()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx) with CTE

```
with cte as(          
 SELECT *,
        ROW_NUMBER() over (order by Image_Id desc) as row_num 
 FROM ImagesInfo)           
 select * from cte where row_num between 2 and 7
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select top 6 * from image_info 
where image_id not in(select max(image_id) from image_info)
order by image_id desc
```